# Check django user outside django

Tags: django

I have one django app and few small Flask webservices.

In Flask apps I need to validate if the client logged in Django app and grab his pk if possible.

It seems to be possible by taking session ID from a cookie and manually looking into session storage, but I am looking for some less low-level solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a REST api to do that. In the api on the django side you would query the user by whatever criteria you provided and return `user.is_authenticated()` and `user.pk`. Take a look at [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) or [tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Then on Flask app you just hit the api and you are done.

Comment: Well DRF will allow me to build an API. But still I need to do something. What you suggest is to send cookies/session id to DRF and check them using django's builtin methods? This looks a little bit inefficient as with Flask web app I am trying to move some traffic and load of django. But with this method Django will still receive a great amount of traffic.

Comment: You should send something like `username` to django app. Then in django you do `User.objects.filter(username=username)` to get the user. I don't know enough about your traffic load, but this is the only `less low-level` way I can think of.

Comment: Imagine user successfully logged on django at http://domain.com. Now on page there is a js which sends requests to some http://api.domain.com/get/some/stuff to fetch an additional data. Or even simpler - connects to some websocet. These services return private data therefore they need to be able to understand that request comes from authenticated user. So he receives only his notifications from websocket, etc. So I need to somehow understand that request comes from js on a page after user logged into django. The only data I have are cookies.